# Clearing and array and filling it with zeros

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I am creating an double array called MySize that will hold user input.

How do I clear an array, by filling it in with all zero using an if statement?

I tried creating a function called ClearMySize to allow the user to clear the entire array that they created and fill it full of zeros

```
package trashmysize;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TrashMySize {

    static double [][] MySize;   
    static int b1 = 0;
    static int b2 = 0;
    static Scanner scanSize = new Scanner(System.in); 
    static int columns = 0;
    static int rows = 0;
    static int NumberOfElements;
    
    static void PrintMySize(){       

        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                System.out.print(MySize[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
}
    
    static void BuildMySize(){
        
        System.out.println("Enter the number of columns: ");
        rows = Integer.parseInt(scanSize.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Enter the number of rows: ");
        columns = Integer.parseInt(scanSize.nextLine());       
        MySize = new double[rows][columns];
        
        
        for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                System.out.print(MySize[r][c] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        Menu();
}
    
    static void UserEntryMySize(){

        int blue = 0;
        double value = 0;
        
        
        while(blue < 1){
            System.out.println("Enter value:  ");
            value = Double.parseDouble(scanSize.nextLine());
            System.out.println("What row:   ");
            b1 = Integer.parseInt(scanSize.nextLine()) -1;
            System.out.println("What column: ");
            b2 = Integer.parseInt(scanSize.nextLine()) -1;
            
            try{
                if(b1 <= rows-1 && b2 <= columns-1){
                    System.out.println("Good position");
                }
                blue++;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Not a good position");  
                blue++;
                BuildMySize();        
            }
        }
        
        
        MySize[b1][b2] = value;
        PrintMySize();
        Menu();
}           
    
    static void ClearMySize(){
                      
        if(MySize != null){
            //for (int i = 0; i < MySize.length; i++) 
                //MySize[i] = 0;
            
            Arrays.fill(MySize, 0);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Array is empty");
        }
        
        System.out.println("\nArray has been cleared: " + Arrays.toString(MySize));
        PrintMySize();
        Menu();
    
    }
    
    static public  void Menu(){
    
    int choice = 0;
        
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\nMain Menu\n"
                + "\n1. Build MySize"
                + "\n2. Add to MySize"
                + "\n3. Clear MySize"
                + "\nMake a choice: ");
        
        choice = Integer.parseInt(myScan.nextLine());
        
        switch(choice){
            case 1 -> BuildMySize();
            case 2 -> UserEntryMySize();
            case 3 -> ClearMySize();
            case 4 -> Menu();
            case 5 -> {
                System.out.println("Thank you for playing! Have a good day!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Menu();
    }
    
}
```

But that doesn't work. It just seems to crash my code.
I keep getting the error message of:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Integer
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:3429)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.ClearMySize(TrashMySize.java:107)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.Menu(TrashMySize.java:136)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.UserEntryMySize(TrashMySize.java:91)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.Menu(TrashMySize.java:135)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.BuildMySize(TrashMySize.java:51)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.Menu(TrashMySize.java:134)
    at trashmysize.TrashMySize.main(TrashMySize.java:145)
C:\Users\Amanda\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trashMySize\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1330: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Amanda\Documents\NetBeansProjects\trashMySize\nbproject\build-impl.xml:936: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 15 seconds)
```

Everything works as it should except for my clear function.

Comment: what is MySize, an array or size of the array?

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.fill( array, 0 );`  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(int%5B%5D,int)

Comment: *"It doesn't work. It just seems to crash my code."* – Well, what error message did you get?

Comment: MySize is the name of the array. I am trying to set up a function called ClearMySize that will clear the data that the user entered into the array. The clear function has to be in an if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest solution is:

```
if(condition)
{
   for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
   {
      array[i] = 0
   }
}
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all indexes and set values to 0.

```
if(array != null){
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++) array[i] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so this is more complicated than the other answers have realized.

The first thing to note is that this is not an simple array.  The array is declared as a:

```
  static double [][] MySize;
```

That is an array of arrays.

(And really seriously, that is an *awful* choice that you have made for the array variable name.  It bears no relation to what the variable means, and it is a major Java style violation to boot.)

You try to fill it like this:

```
  Arrays.fill(MySize, 0);
```

So now we look at the overloads for `Arrays.fill` and we see that there are three overloads that *might* be relevant:

```
 Arrays.fill(int[], int);       #1 

 Arrays.fill(double[], double); #2

 Arrays.fill(Object[], Object); #3
```

The first one does not apply because `double[][]` is not compatible with `int[]` (though the 2nd argument matches exactly).

The second one does not apply because `double[][]` is not compatible with `double[]`.  (The second argument is compatible by a primitive widening conversion.)

The third one does apply because `double[][]` **IS** compatible with `Object[]`, because `double[]` is a subtype of `Object`.  However, for that to "work", the `Object` you are supplying as the 2nd argument needs to be a `double[]`.  It it isn't.  It is an `int`.  And Java is performing a boxing conversion to turn that into a `Integer` ... 'cos that is what the JLS says it should do.

So as a result, `fill` will attempt to assign an `Integer` into a cell of an array `double[]` ... which throws an exception.

Lesson #1.  Be careful with multi-dimensional array types in Java.  They are not entirely intuitive.

Lesson #2.  Only use `Array.fill(...)` for 1D arrays.

---

The actual solution here is this:

```
for (double[] d: MySize) {
    Arrays.fill(d, 0.0);
}
```

or you could you could use a nested `for` loop and do the filling by hand.

Comment: Thank you. I know, all the variables are not great in this project but we didn't have a choice on the names. That did work but it has to be presented in an if statement.

Comment: I modified this a bit and got it to work enough to turn in the homework project!! Thank you so much!